# Is there a single function to check an array contains another array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
[1,2,3].CONTAINS([1,2]) ==> true
[1,2,3].CONTAINS([1,2,3,4]) ==> false
```

or

```
{a:1,b:2,c:3}.HASKEYS([a,b]) ==> true
{a:1,b:2,c:3}.HASKEYS([a,b,c,d]) ==> false
```

Is there a single function to check an array contains another array?

Comment: +1 as there's nothing wrong with the question. I don't believe there is a ready one, you'll be better off writing your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, but you can make one:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(other) {
    for (var i = 0; i < other.length; i++) {
        if (this.indexOf(other[i]) === -1) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And if order matters:

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(other) {
    var broken;

    if (!other.length) return true;

    for (var i = 0; i < this.length - other.length + 1; i++) {
        broken = false;

        for (var j = 0; j < other.length; j++) {
            if (this[i + j] !== other[j]) {
                broken = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!broken) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The other function is similar, so I'll leave it to you to finish:

```
Object.prototype.has_keys = function(keys) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The question is likely not detailed enough, but from it, I was expecting "[1,2,3].contains([2,1])" should return false. Your implementation makes it return true.

Comment: nicely done @Blender, I think another loop is needed in there to detect all occurrences of other[0]. Otherwise the following returns false: "[1,2,3,2,1].contains([2,1])"

Comment: @TimothéeGroleau: Yep, thanks. I have a feeling that there may be a nicer way of writing it.